# Unable to change background color of TF in search bar implemented using UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

How to change the background color of **only textfield**? (which is red in the below image)

[image]

If is set the background colour to white using the code below then there is not enough top padding
`searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this for change the background color of textfield in search bar.**

> We have many ways to do that:
>
> **First way:**

```
extension UISearchBar {

    private func getViewElement<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {

        let svs = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
        guard let element = (svs.filter { $0 is T }).first as? T else { return nil }
        return element
    }

    func setTextFieldColor(color: UIColor) {

        if let textField = getViewElement(type: UITextField.self) {
            switch searchBarStyle {
                case .minimal:
                    textField.layer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
                    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 6

                case .prominent, .default:
                    textField.backgroundColor = color
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **How to use**

```
searchBar.setTextFieldColor(color: UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.3))
```

> **Second way:** You can get textfield from searchbar like that and change the color directly:

**In Swift**

```
for subView: UIView? in searchBar.subviews {
    for field: Any? in subView?.subviews ?? [Any?]() {
        if (field is UITextField) {
            var textField = field as? UITextField
            textField?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }
    }
}
```

**In Obj-c**

```
for (UIView *subView in _searchBar.subviews) {
    for(id field in subView.subviews){
        if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)field;
            [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you mixing Swift and Objective-C codes in the answer on purpose? :)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift :

```
var textField = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as? UITextField
textField?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red   // Change as per your requirement
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need below search bar extension:

```
extension UISearchBar {
    /// Return text field inside a search bar
    var textField: UITextField? {
        guard let text = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField else {
            return nil
        }

        return text
    }
}
```

then at your view controller:

```
searchBar.textField?.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That's a silver bullet, for sure.